# Why does quicksort need to recurse over "sorted" subsection?

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting

still pretty new to alg/data structures been trying to learn how to apply quicksort.

I found the following implementation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/quick-sort/

The portion which confuses me:

```
/* The main function that implements QuickSort() 
      arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
      low  --> Starting index, 
      high  --> Ending index */
    void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
    { 
        if (low < high) 
        { 
        /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is  
          now at right place */
        int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 

        // Recursively sort elements before 
        // partition and after partition 
        sort(arr, low, pi-1); 
        sort(arr, pi+1, high); 
    } 
}
```

It seems to me that we shouldn't have to recurse over the sort(arr, low, pi-1) section because the algorithm is supposed to have sorted that portion already...

Comment: Do you know what `partition` does?

Comment: Partitioning does not sort either side...it just guarantees that everything on the left is less and everything to the right is greater than the partition.

Comment: What gives you the idea that that section is already sorted?

Answer (score 1):

In your implementation of quicksort, I commented out in some places to make it more clear about the idea behind quicksort. In your code where you calculated variable `pi` using `partition` function, all the elements before index `pi` are less than `arr[pi]` but these are not guaranteed that they are in sorted order.Also, all the elements after index `pi` are greater than `arr[pi]` but these are not guaranteed to be in sorted order. I have commented out in your code below:

```
int partition (arr[], low, high)
{
   // pivot (Element to be placed at right position)
   pivot = arr[high];  
   i = (low - 1)  // Index of smaller element
   for (j = low; j <= high- 1; j++)
   {
    // If current element is smaller than or equal to pivot
    /* But, it does not guaranteed that smaller elements will come in sorted fashion*/
    if (arr[j] <= pivot)
    {
        i++;    // increment index of smaller element
        swap arr[i] and arr[j]
     }
   }
   swap arr[i + 1] and arr[high])
   return (i + 1)
 }

/* The main function that implements QuickSort() 
  arr[] --> Array to be sorted, 
  low  --> Starting index, 
  high  --> Ending index */
 void sort(int arr[], int low, int high) 
 { 
    if (low < high) 
    { 
    /* pi is partitioning index, arr[pi] is  
      now at right place */
     int pi = partition(arr, low, high); 
     /*Here, all the elements before index pi are less than arr[pi] but 
       not guaranteed that they are in sorted order.
       Also, all the elements after index pi are greater than arr[pi] but 
       not guaranteed to be in sorted order.
     */
     // Recursively sort elements before 
     // partition and after partition 
     sort(arr, low, pi-1); 
     sort(arr, pi+1, high); 
  } 
}
```